# Exposing KubeRay prometheus metrics configuration on head service annotations

Tags: kubernetes, ray

I deployed a ray cluster on Kubernetes using kuberay and I want to monitor the cluster using prometheus metrics. After reading ray document, I know that there is service discovery file is generated on the head node `/tmp/ray/prom_metrics_service_discovery.json`. Using the below Prometheus config, Prometheus will automatically update the addresses that it scrapes based on the contents of Ray’s service discovery file.

```yaml
# Prometheus config file

# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     2s
  evaluation_interval: 2s

# Scrape from Ray.
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'ray'
  file_sd_configs:
  - files:
    - '/tmp/ray/prom_metrics_service_discovery.json'
```

But since I am using Kubernetes, based on humble experience, I think the most convenient way to configure Prometheus to scape the ray metrics should be exposing metrics configuration on service annotations like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxx
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8081"
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

Updated at 2022-11-10
I manually add an Kubernetes service to solve this problem.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # labels:
  #   app.kubernetes.io/name: kuberay-metrics
  #   ray.io/cluster: {{ include "ray-cluster.fullname" . }}
  name: {{ include "ray-cluster.fullname" . }}-metrics-svc
  annotations:
    {{- if .Values.prometheus.enable }}
    prometheus.io/scrape: "{{.Values.prometheus.enable }}"
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    {{- end }}
spec:
  ports:
  - name: metrics
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kuberay
    ray.io/cluster: {{ include "ray-cluster.fullname" . }}
  type: ClusterIP
```

Answer (score 1):

Re: Is there any way to achieve this?

-- I don't think so, not yet!
I think this would be great to discuss in a [KubeRay feature request GitHub issue](https://github.com/ray-project/kuberay/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature-request.yml&title=%5BFeature%5D+). Please feel free to post there!